# Variables can't be resolved to a variable within the for loop

Tags: java, variables

For some reason, when I try to run this code, it always return that it can't find the symbol `b`. Then I found that the problem was that the variable `b` can't be resolved to a variable. I have no idea why it is unable to resolve it to a variable.

```
class Q5 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int iMus = 0; iMus < 10; iMus++)
    {
      int b = 19 + iMus;
    }
    System.out.println(b);
  }
}
```

Comment: because b only exists in the scope of the for loop.  Maybe you meant to put the println in the loop?

Comment: When a local variable is declared, inside a pair of braces `{ }`, it ceases to exist once the `}` is reached.  In this case, that's before your `System.out.println` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you declared the variable `b` within the loop. You try to print and access the variable outside the scope of the loop. That is not possible and please define the variable `b` outside the loop's scope. I will show an example below.

```
class Q5 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int b = 0;
    for (int iMus = 0; iMus < 10; iMus++)
    {
      b = 19 + iMus;
    }
    System.out.println(b);
  }
}
```